# why not use static function-pointers in c++

Tags: c++, pointers

I want a maintainable array/list of possible functions/behaviors, each representing another mode of operation, and I want to change the 'mode' simply by changing a variable storing the pointer to the right function. 
 With researching I found the fact, that function-pointers are a bit smelly, but I wonder if 
A
it is okay in my usecase to use them anyway
B
there is a better/professional option.

Some pseudocode to show my prefered way of using it:

```
// store references to the modes and an information about the active mode
void * allModePointers[3];
int modeNumber = 2;

// call the active mode
(*allModePointers[modeNumber])();
```

Comment: Function pointers smell just fine to me.

Comment: Agree, but: Look at `std::function` too. More things are possible with it, maybe you'll realize at some point that you actually need it.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Well, may be not in that degenerated manner :-P ...

Comment: You can write the call as `allModePointers[modeNumber]()`, which looks slightly less ugly.

Comment: @melpomene: You could, if `allModePointers` did store function pointers. As it stands, [allModePointers stores pointers to void](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=void+*+allModePointers%5B3%5D).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`void*` is quite liberal with what type it accepts. By using it you give up compile time type checking. It is also hard to understand without `typedef void* ModeFunctionPtr`.

To get type checking and avoid pointer casting, you need a properly declared function pointer array like `void(*allModePointers[3])()` (verified by [cdecl.org](http://cdecl.org/)). This only works when the function signatures match, and if they don't, you are doing something wrong.

In the end, I would recommend `std::function`, which is a wrapper for callable objects. It has the advantage of being able to accept lambda expression, and works well with other `std` functions like `std::bind` if you one day find that static functions are not enough.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** When using C++ the most professional way to implement behaviors that do not readily exist in a library is to use a class.

**Specific advice:** if I understand your intent correctly, you want to model something like a terminal (*i.e.* performs a task based on a command). What I would do is make a class that only has functions (I have done this before to model a calculator) and maybe some static constants thrown in if you need them. One of the functions will be a control function that just takes in the command and calls one of the other functions based on that command, then returns the answer. Throw it in a .h, make it look neat with Doxygen and *voila!* You have your maintainable list of behaviors. I will demonstrate below using my calculator example. The one I made was to do vector calc, but I will make a simple one that only adds and squares.

```
/* doxygen comments */
/* include guards, includes, etc, etc */

class Calculator{

    public:
        /* static constants if needed (i.e. pi, e, ...) */
        /* constructor, destructor, getters if you want to make the
           constants private */

        /* doxygen comments */
        double run( int function_id, double x, double y ){

            switch( function_id ){

                case 0: return add( x, y );
                case 1: return square( x );
                default: return x; //why not?
            } 
        }

    private:
        /* doxygen comments */
        inline double square( double x ) { return x*x; }

        /* doxygen comments */
        inline double add( double x, double y ) { return x+y; }
};
```

Although this example is a little different than mine because I actually just made all the functions public and called them myself from main. Anyway, you get the gist, but there's probably less memory expensive ways of doing it as well.

Comment: *"there's probably less memory expensive ways of doing it as well"* - Considering, that your class has no memory requirements (and thus `sizeof(Calculator)` returns 1), I doubt that there is.

Comment: Thanks, that's a fine way of doing it. I will not use a class in my case though, cause it's just a single set of modes, tailored to one application. Also I like, that with pointers it's easier to have modes containing submodes containing submodes and so on, without having to declare every possible combination in a switch-case.